# Angular - load different styles by different environment

Tags: angular

I have an application with two different views, every view run with lazy loading by his environment.

For example, if i run `ng serve --configuration=viewA` .

The views use shared components by shared module.

My question, is it possible to use different css file for each environment?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to create 2 different projects in your angular.json file

```
projects
  app_name
    ...
  app_name-e2e
    ...
```

Each project can have its own configuration properties like styles, scripts, aot etc. In your case you just have to specify two different styles remaining everything will be the same then just run the app like this:

```
ng serve <project_name>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i thought on that solution but is requires a huge refactor for the project, i will try that solution if there is no better way.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is asked a lot [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5803) 
Maybe you can achieve a solution with the filereplacement workaround which is described at the end of the feature request :)

Comment: It works well for me, the only problem is that i need to write all the style again just for one or two properties that i want to change.

Comment: Hm.. maybe add foreach style a css file which contains the changed values as css variable and replacing this file?

Comment: First of all thank for the help, do you mean to import in my scss file a variables.scss and replace it!? That if so what file name i write in the import line?

Comment: hm yeah, you are right.. the filename has to be the same..
like so:
`
"fileReplacements": [
      {
        "replace": "src/styles/template1/variables.scss"
        "with": "src/styles/template2/variables.scss"
      }
`
didn't tried this.. sorry If this is all wrong :/

Comment: It's not working, i dont know why but the import in the file.component.scss still went to the original var.scss, although i can make scss file that contains the css classes i want to override and put it in the styleUrl in the @component and replace it by env...

Comment: seems like this is another feature which doesn't work with angular cli..
someone posted a workaround here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/11451#issuecomment-424715627